# Regular Expression to parse string using pdf-reader

Tags: regex, string, str-replace, pdf-reader

Well, I have to parse this line in Ruby on Rails

```
TD(AQ-163W-1B2V) Tj0.00 -13.52 TD(AQ-180W-7BV) Tj0.00 -13.48 TD(AW-48HE-1AV) Tj0.00 -13.52 TD(AW-48HE-8AV) Tj0.00 -13.48 TD(AW-49H-7EV) Tj0.00 -13.52 TD(AW-80D-1AV) Tj0.00 -13.48 TD(AW-80D-2AV)
```

I need a regular expression to store only data inside TD, without parenthesis. In this case it will be:

```
["AQ-163W-1B2V", "AQ-180W-7BV", "AW-48HE-1AV", etc.]
```

Any idea? 
Thanks!

Comment: Which lang your running?

Comment: Sorry, Im running ruby on rails

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `string.scan`

```
> s = "TD(AQ-163W-1B2V) Tj0.00 -13.52 TD(AQ-180W-7BV) Tj0.00 -13.48 TD(AW-48HE-1AV)"
> s.scan(/\(([^()]+)\)/)
=> [["AQ-163W-1B2V"], ["AQ-180W-7BV"], ["AW-48HE-1AV"]]
> s.scan(/(?<=\()[^()]+(?=\))/)
=> ["AQ-163W-1B2V", "AQ-180W-7BV", "AW-48HE-1AV"]
```